# Drawing a partial circle with path

Tags: svg, geometry

I'm trying to draw a partial circle with svg's path. I have the circle center coordinates, radius and the start/end coordinates (where the partial circle will end), but I can't wrap my head around on how to draw the circle.

Comment: [SVG Arc](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands)?

Comment: So you need a "pizza slice" of a circle? Is it important that it is a path? An alternative could be to mask off a circle, so that you end with the slice that you need - would that be an option for you?

Comment: try: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this small example can help you. The path starts in 50%,50% (center), moves to 50%,0 (that is 12 o'clock), creates an arc where radius x and y are 50 (the fist two numbers after a) and ends in the position that is a calculation with sin() and cos() on 45 degrees (the angle should be in radians). The three numbers in between (0 0 1) are flags.

See more here: [d - Elliptical Arc Curve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#elliptical_arc_curve)

```js
// 45 deg:
console.log(Math.cos(Math.PI/4)*50, 50-Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*50);

document.querySelector('path')
  .setAttribute('d', `M50,50 L50,0 a 50 50 0 0 1 ${Math.cos(Math.PI/4)*50} ${50-Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*50} z`);
```

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="lightblue" />
  <path fill="navy" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The way you described it makes sense, you've been of great help!